# Copy/Paste Table with Autonumbering between MS Word Documents While Preserving Numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an MS Word document with tables using autonumbering like so:
[image: example table]

I would like to copy/paste these tables to a new MS Word document while preserving the numbering, e.g.
[image: example paste (desired)]

But the numbering gets reset:

[image: example paste (actual)]

How can I paste in a new document with the original autonumbered values retained? All the paste options (Keep Source Formatting, Merge Formatting, Use Destination Styles, Picture) result in the numbers getting reset, except Keep Text Only, which of course loses all the table formatting.

I'm open to solutions that involve copying into a intermediate like Excel as well! Just so I don't have to manually type the numbers.

This is Word for Office 365 (version 2104) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to, in a copy of your source, apply the vba command:

```
activedocument.ConvertNumbersToText
```

Then, copy and paste from that copy. When d one, discard the copy.

How to use vba from a website or forum.

- [Graham Mayor's page](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm)
- [Greg Maxey's page](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html)